# How to Kill Serverx.exe manaually

Tags: virus

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](https://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware)

A few days ago, I got a serverx.exe virus in my computer. And it gave me double headache when using the computer. I can't open **now Microsoft application** and **other software**, moreover I can't **install some of the softwares** such as gom player or vlc and some other softwares. Above the following problems, I searched at online about that problem. I got some of the answer about it. It said like to **delete the serverx.exe in system32 and all the value and key in the regedit concerning the serverx.exe and then to del Internet Explorer folder**. So, I did as they said. But, I still have serverx.exe in my computer.

Thus, Could anyone help me about this virus to kill manually or using writing bat files? I will be hoping the answer!

Comment: Get Malwarebytes Recently I just have the same problem on my sisters laptop and this really remove the `xxx.exe` file out and then you can use the computer as usual

Comment: The official link to the MalwareBytes web site is:  http://www.malwarebytes.org/

Answer (score 0):

I would use the SysInternals application [PendMoves](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb897556) to schedule that file for deletion upon next reboot, and then shut the machine down - pulling the plug is probably a better option than doing a normal shut down as it gives the rogue process very little opportunity to do anything.

Of course this is done at your own risk and is not guaranteed to work, as malware will frequently have other watcher processes designed to interfere with or undo any actions that impede the malware. This also doesn't guarantee that you won't be reinfected, it just potentially gives you a little breathing space.

Alternatively you could download free versions of some of the various anti-virus products and use them. [Microsoft's Security Essentials](http://www.microsoft.com/en-nz/security_essentials/default.aspx) may help here, otherwise try one of the other big vendors like kaspersky or Eset or AVG.